# Installing gtk+ themes on Windows

Tags: windows, themes, gtk

How do I download a gtk+ theme and install it on a computer running Windows?

I know that I can select a few of the themes from the theme selector, but not sure how I install one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

looks like the '[gtk-preference-tool](http://sourceforge.net/userapps/mediawiki/alex-sh/index.php?title=GTK%2B_Preference_Tool)' is part of the '[installer](http://sourceforge.net/userapps/mediawiki/alex-sh/index.php?title=Main_Page)':

```
GTK+ Preference Tool is an utility for easy theme and font 
switching for GTK+ applications. You can download the utility
as a standalone source/binary in the Downloads section. It is 
also included in the latest GTK+ Themes packages.
```

Comment: The links seem to be broken. =/

Comment: Link broken again.