# How do I change the theme of gEdit on WIndows?

Tags: windows-7, gedit

Gedit (like most Windows GTK applications) is hideously ugly. I already tried the solution described in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/124922/23420), however, it a) prompted me to install an endless array of DLLs and finally failing, and b) the site seems to be down at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### First, you will need:

- I don't know where you got a Windows version of Gedit from and whether it came with a GTK+ runtime, so I cannot say if this is correct or necessary, but:

  [GTK+ runtime](https://sourceforge.net/userapps/mediawiki/alex-sh/index.php?title=Downloads) ([2010-10-21](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gtk-win/gtk2-runtime-2.22.0-2010-10-21-ash.exe?download)) if you want to use the "MS-Windows" theme with (almost-)native Windows appearance.

  You *may* need to install it to `\Program Files\Common Files\GTK\2.0` instead of the suggested path.
- The GTK-Win [themes package](https://sourceforge.net/userapps/mediawiki/alex-sh/index.php?title=Downloads) ([2009-09-07](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gtk-win/gtk2-themes-2009-09-07-ash.exe?download)) comes with a Theme Chooser application and lots of other themes. (I find *Clearlooks* much nicer than *MS-Windows*.)

#### Then, pick a theme.

- If you installed the GTK-Win Themes package, it will come with a theme chooser which can be launched from the Start Menu.
- If you cannot use the Theme Chooser for some reason, create a file **`%UserProfile%\.gtkrc-2.0`** (on your Windows 7, `C:\Users\digitxp\.gtkrc-2.0` or something similar), with contents:

  ```
  gtk-theme-name = "MS-Windows"
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the path tip! It did the trick :) I was putting a `gtkrc` in `%AppData%` to no avail.